# Local "path" repository doesn't see vcs version information

Tags: php, git, composer-php, config

I'm currently trying to setup a better local development without putting information about my local structure into a project itself or into the `composer.json` of this project.

I found out, that there is a new way to do this by using a `config.json` and adding a `"repositories"` section to it, that points to my local projects I depend on.

**My setup**

So I setup two projects with a few versions (on Win10 with IIS 10 with PHP 7.0), lets call them `php-project1` and `php-project2`. `php-project1` depends on `php-project2` and I want to develop both of them at the same time. Changes I make in `php-project2` should therefore directly influence the first project. In addition they are git repositories and they contain tags as composer versions. They are also on packagist, but of course I want to use the local version for development.

Their `composer.json` look like this (2 files):

```
{
    "name": "test/php-project1",
    "description": "Some text here",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "test/php-project2": "^0.3",
    }
}

{
    "name": "test/php-project2",
    "description": "Some other text here",
    "type": "library"
}
```

Please note that there is no `"version"` entry, because I want to use this from the git tags.

Now I tried to setup a global `config.json` like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/somePath/php-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using `php-*` here because I want to use it later for all my repositories/projects with this pattern.

**So what's the problem now?**

When running `composer update` on the first project it doesn't use the local version of `php-project2`, but instead downloads it from packagist. This only works when I add a `"version"` entry to the `composer.json`, but I don't want this!
I also tried `"type": "vcs"`, but this creates a clone and I need a symlink, to have changes directly in other projects too.

The [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) says:

> If the package is a local VCS repository, the version may be inferred by the branch or tag that is currently checked out. Otherwise, the version should be explicitly defined in the package's composer.json file.

Currently `php-project2` is on tag `0.3.0` without any changes.
So what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake with help of [alcohol](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5431) (this sounds wrong though^^).

When you use this and need a symlink, be sure to add a `"version"` entry to your `composer.json` or (in my case) checkout the tag (not the branch!), so composer may see, that your used version matches the required.